# JavaScript: Uncaught RangeError

Tags: javascript

I'm having an error which if I declared `this.property` instead of `this._property`. What is the problem here?

Here is the code:

```
class Persoana {
    constructor(prenume, nume, varsta) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.varsta = varsta;
    }
    get info() {
        return `${this.prenume} ${this.nume}`;
    }
    set varsta(val) {
        console.log(`setter varsta: ${val}`);
        this.varsta = val;
    }
}
let ray = new Persoana("ray", "stone", 30);
console.log(ray.info);
```

and I have this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded     at Persoana.set varsta [as varsta] (practice4.js:25)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

When you have a setter for a property, then anything that sets the property will implicitly call the setter — even from within the setter function. When a function directly calls itself unconditionally, you get that stack error.

Generally people use some kind of convention for "companion" properties like that:

```
set varsta(val) {
    console.log(`setter varsta: ${val}`);
    this._varsta = val;
}
```

In that case you also need a getter:

```
get varsta() { return this._varsta; }
```